# Error in Azure DevOps website deployment on IIS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a dotnet application(vs 2017) build on Azure DevOps. I am trying to deploy the artifacts generated onto local IIS. However after doing all the process i get the following error.

[image: Error]

[image: error2]

[image: error3]

[image: agent]

[image: agent2]

[image: agent3]

[image: agent4]

Can someone assist in resolving the same.

Comment: You mention 'deploy local'. What does that mean? Do you have a VM with a Build Agent set up and you want to deploy on that VM?

Comment: @Salman where is the agent running?

Comment: @RobBos Question updated.

Comment: @ZairHenrique please check the update

Comment: What is your server OS?

Comment: What do you mean by Local IIS? Is this your desktop? Server manager will only work on WinServer agents.

Comment: @RobBos I have IIS running on my Windows system.

Comment: @ZairHenrique Yes it is IIS manager on my system. It is windows system.

Comment: What version of Windows Server are you running? 2008R2, 2014, 2016??

Comment: @RobBos I have windows 8.1, so it must be server 2012. At present  im working on another system.

Comment: If you are working on Windows 8.1, you have a 'Desktop OS'. As @ZairHenrique already mentioned, you can only use the Server Manager on a 'Windows Server OS'

Comment: You are missing the PowerShell module 'ServerManager'.

Answer (score 0):

IIS Web App manager will only work on Windows Server machines as it will try to use 'servermanager', only available on WinServer.

As you are running this agent on your local machine, which is a Windows desktop system, you should use other way to deploy on your release pipeline (powershell scripts/cmd).